# Windows Storage Server 2008 hangs at logon

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, storage-server

We have a Dell PowerVault NX-3000 server running Windows Server 2008. Every now and then, when I try to login, the server seems to hang at the Welcome screen after I type in the password. However, all other services on the server are running fine - users are able to print off the print server and access their files. It just won't let me login. Any idea why this is happening?

P.S.: I can't look at the server logs, because it won't let me login in the first place. Remote administration is also disabled on the server, so I can't use Remote Administration tools to look at the logs.

Comment: I'm assuming that you don't have access to change so you can administer remote administration and view the logs. Do you have access to the console to login with that and view the logs. If you can't get logged in at all and you can't view any logs, there's not much you can do.

Comment: I ended up hard-rebooting the server. Now I've enabled remote event log administration and remote server management so that I can investigate this issue when it happens the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling RDP [remotely](http://oreilly.com/windows/archive/server-hacks-remote-desktop.html) and reboot the server after hours using the following command:

`shutdown /m:\\server /r /t 15`

Comment: RDP was already enabled. (Remote administration is not enabled.) The same problem occurs then too. The screen hangs at the welcome screen.

Comment: Is that a domain-connected server?

Comment: Yes it is a domain-connected server.

Comment: What defined as DNS on the card?

Comment: Try disconnecting (physically) the server from the network before rebooting it. If it works, check the network configuration and the remove the server from the domain and add it again.